# Struts2 list of default interceptors

Tags: struts2

I can't find the list of interceptors used in the defaultStack. My app works when I use the defaultStack but I don't want to have all the interceptors, only the ones I need (like I don't want the CSP interceptor contained in the defaultStack).

Where can I find this list?

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, we can find it in `struts-default.xml`:

```xml
<interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="cspInterceptor">
                    <param name="enforcingMode">false</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="datetime"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="coepInterceptor">
                    <param name="enforcingMode">false</param>
                    <param name="disabled">false</param>
                    <param name="exemptedPaths"/>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="coopInterceptor">
                    <param name="exemptedPaths"/>
                    <param name="mode">same-origin</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="fetchMetadata"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
```

Comment: It's also in [the docs](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/interceptors).